# Errno::ENOENT when uploading an image using Carrierwave and MiniMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

My rails app has an image upload which uses the latest versions of Carrierwave and MiniMagick. It works great on the server, but in my local host which is WEBrick and Windows 7, i get this error when i try and upload an image:

```
Errno::ENOENT in PostsController#create

No such file or directory - identify -ping C:/Users/Ryan/AppData/Local/Temp/mini_magick20121024-6068-g2bed8.jpg
```

I go to the path and the image actually exists, i'm not sure what prevents Carrierwave or MiniMagick from reading it.

Any one has an idea?

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed?  Can you run the identify command manually on the console?

Comment: @JasonNoble I feel embarrassed as i thought MiniMagick comes with ImageMagick, thanks so much for pointing that out!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have ImageMagick installed? Can you run the identify command manually on the console?

The reason I ask is it appears your error message is what occurs when it can't find the identify commend, which is part of ImageMagick.

Comment: Yes it is misleading as you first think from the error message that the file path cannot be found, but installing ImageMagick binaries also solved it for me.

Comment: @wolle Im having the same issue... I downloaded Imagemagick for mac and added the rmagick gem..but still the same error. How did you do the install?